# Does tomcat detect changes in decompressed war?

Tags: java, testing, tomcat

I have a problem with Tomcat. It hangs. I suppose that this is because I have change one XML file inside decompressed folder inside webapps. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: need more info - how much memory does your TOmcat run on in first place? what does hang mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not because the change of the xml file itself. However, if you change web.xml, web application will be redeployed, and each redeploy causes memory leak, which eventually will lead to hangout.